# Why JSP page is not displaying java object values?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I created a simple application using Spring MVC(annotation based) and I am not able to view the results on JSP page. Below is the code which I have written:
In my AppConfig class:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

in my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listNonClosedDeployments(ModelMap model) {
    //DB operations to get the data
    model.addAttribute("testMsg", "deployments are opened");
    return "success";
}
```

My success JSP is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>
<head>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
</head>
<body>
${testMsg}
</body>
</html>
```

My output page is:

```
 ${testMsg}
```

Could you please let me know what am I missing here?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

it is not displaying the value because JSP's Expression Language is disabled by default. You have to enable it manually.
Add the below line to the top of your jsp page:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```